# SQL: Getting the count to return 0 while using group by in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to receive a count of records on different days when no such records are associated for an example.

My example table contains the following columns: `date_created` and `key`

What I would like to see is:

```
date              count
----------        -----
2014-01-27        3
2014-01-26        0
2014-01-25        1
```

But What I see is :

```
date              count
----------        -----
2014-01-27        3
2014-01-25        1
```

Here is my query that I'm running which will only give me the count if a record exists:

```
SELECT CAST(created_date as date), COUNT(*)  
FROM TEST 
WHERE CAST(created_date as date) >= '2014-01-21' AND
      CAST(created_date as date) <= '2014-08-02' AND
      key = 'foobar'
GROUP BY CAST(created_date as date)
```

Apologies if I have done some unnecessary things. From what I've researched, I've seen some solutions using left joins; however, as a beginner of SQL, I am really having some difficulty understanding the logic.

Comment: why you are casting `created_date` ? If its datetime or date datatype no need to do so. If its varchar then you may need to use `str_to_date()`. Try adding some sample data on sqlfiddle.com for debug the issue.

Comment: Hi Abhik, I am casting it because it includes a time stamp, but I do not need that information. I basically want to know on each day the count of records, so I cast the datetime to a simple date to basically chop off the timestamp.

Comment: There is no record with the date `2014-01-26`...

Comment: @zhongxiao37 That's correct, so I would like to display that date as well as display a count of 0.

Comment: You should have `calendar` table for that to work, because there is no other way to fill the date gaps. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514901/group-by-day-with-filled-gaps   By the way, you might want to use `DATE()` instead of `CAST()` as it's easier to understand

Comment: I see Stan. I was hoping that I could do it with just one table, but it looks like that is not the case. If you would like to post your reply as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mark that question as answered I'll repost my comment:

You should have `calendar` table for that to work, because there is no other way to fill the date gaps. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514901/group-by-day-with-filled-gaps) might help you.

By the way, you might want to use `DATE()` instead of `CAST()` as it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a calendar table so that you have a complete list of dates you are interested in.  For example, starting with this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (created_date datetime, keytext varchar(200));
CREATE TABLE CalendarDays (date datetime);

INSERT INTO test (created_date, keytext) VALUES ('2014-1-1', 'foobar'), ('2014-1-5', 'foobar');    
INSERT INTO CalendarDays values ('2014-1-1'), ('2014-1-2'), ('2014-1-3'), ('2014-1-4'), ('2014-1-5')
```

You could then use a sql statement like this to give you the result you are looking for.

```
select d.date, count(t.keytext)
from calendarDays as d
  left join test as t on d.date = t.created_date
group by d.date;
```

This is probably where I should mention that this is just an example, and you will need to determine the proper way to build the query for performance based on how much data is in your table/indexes etc.